# How to update the key value of json string in python

Tags: python, json

I have a script where I will get the data from the following JSON string:

```
Process_details = { "process_dtls":[{"process_name":"process1","process_id":1},{"process_name":"process2","process_id":2},
{"process_name":"process1","process_id":3}]}
```

I want to loop all the process and I should be able to update the key values.

Below is the code I have now, but it is not updating the key value.

```
for i in Process_details["process_dtls"]:
     i['process_id']= 0
```

Comment: Once JSON has been read into a Python data structure it is no longer JSON. It's just native Python, in this case a dict where the only key's value is a list of dicts.

Comment: Remember that, after you change the dict, you have to use `json.dumps` to convert it back to JSON.

Comment: This code does update all the `process_id` fields to 0.  If that isn't happening for you, then there must be other code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Nothing is happening, it still remains as the same

Comment: I have did the same thing by having a .json file where I can update any key value but I wanted to know whether we can update the value of this json string within .py file

Comment: Updating the `Process_details` variable won't automatically update the json file it came from, if that's what you wanted...